# How to use bomradarloop python library?

Tags: python, function

I want to collect Bureau of Meteorology (BOM) radar images using Python, but there is no documentation of how to use the library functions.

The library can be found [here](https://pypi.org/project/bomradarloop/#files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open cmd line

> `windows key + r` then type `cmd` then press `enter` key

2. Install the python library

> `pip install bomradarloop`

3. Write your python file

> from bomradarloop import BOMRadarLoop

4. In your python file you can call the functions of the BOMRadarLoop class.

> my_radar = BOMRadarLoop()

#Return the current BOM radar-loop image:

> my_radar.current()

#Fetch the background map, then the topography, locations (e.g. city names), and distance from-radar range markings, and merge into a single image:

> my_radar._background()

#Fetch a radar image for each expected time, composite it with a common background image, then overlay on the legend to produce a frame. Collect and return the frames, ignoring any blanks. If no frames were produced, return None (the caller must expect this):

> my_radar._frames()

#Fetch an image from the BOM:

> my_radar._image()

#Return the currently available frame images for the given radar, extracted from the BOM's HTML:

> my_radar._image_names()

#Fetch the BOM colorbar legend image:

> my_radar._legend()

#Return an animated GIF comprising a set of frames, where each frame includes a background, one or more supplemental layers, a colorbar legend, and a radar image:

> my_radar._loop()

#Return a full URL to a resource on the BOM site:

> my_radar._url()